# Getting MySQL error code 1064 on an INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I've poured over this and can't find what could possible be causing the error. Any suggestions?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `firstname`, 
        `lastname`, `photo`, `mobile`, `fax`, `bday`, `homeadd`, `city`,
        `state`, `zip`, `mailingadd`, `altfax`, `altphone`, `email`,
        `emailpass`, `website`, `bio`, `designations`, `photo2`, `type`,
        `confirmed_email`, `registered_on`, `disabled`, `admin_disabled`)
        VALUES (NULL, $username, MD5('$password'), $firstname, $lastname, 
        '', 'test', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $email, '', '', '', '',
        '', 'agent', '1', NOW(), $disabled, 0)";`
```

Comment: Give us the full error message please.

Answer (score 1):

Add escaping to all string values. 
Here is php function: [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). 
And you should refactor your code with using [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should still be in single quotes. Anytime you are inserting a `'$variable'`, throw single quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes around your individual values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,firstname,lastname,photo,mobile,fax,bday,homeadd,city,state,zip,mailingadd,altfax,altphone,email,emailpass,website,bio,designations,photo2,type,confirmed_email,registered_on,disabled,admin_disabled) VALUES (NULL, '$username', MD5('$password'), '$firstname', '$lastname', '', 'test', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '$email', '', '', '', '', '', 'agent', '1', NOW(), $disabled, 0)";
```

Comment: Now it's saying column count doesn't match row count... even though it clearly does...

Comment: Did you copy paste this answer? The syntax is this answer is incorrect. You need single quotes around `'$disabled'` as well.

Comment: Quotes are not "needed" around $disabled if disabled is either a boolean or INT, but I agree that it would be recommended if the content is uncertain. I also recommend Stanislav's answer, as it ensures that any single-quotes have been property escaped, which may be the cause of your continuing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting the variables:

```
$sql       = "INSERT INTO users 
(`id`, `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `photo`, `mobile`, `fax`, `bday`, `homeadd`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `mailingadd`, `altfax`, `altphone`, `email`, `emailpass`, `website`, `bio`, `designations`, `photo2`, `type`, `confirmed_email`, `registered_on`, `disabled`, `admin_disabled`) VALUES 
(NULL, '$username', MD5('$password'), '$firstname', '$lastname', '', 'test', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '$email', '', '', '', '', '', 'agent', '1', NOW(), '$disabled', 0)";
```

I'd really recommend getting away from the mysql_* functions since they're deprecated and won't work in future versions. If you use PDO or MySQLi, you can use the binding functions so you don't have to worry about quoting the values.